# how to break line in ruby on rails after X characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using this code to display the headline if there is one

```
<%= @user.headline if @user.headline? %>
```

I have it limited to 100 characters. How can I break this headline after 50 characters and display the broken part below? I am planning to have them centered in two lines.

**For example:**

If this is the headline which goes over 100 characters then I want to display it like this

**Display:**

If this is the headline which goes over 100 characters then

I want to display it like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use word_wrap from text helper:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
# or in a controller
# helper :text

word_wrap(@user.headline, :line_width => 50)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`word_wrap`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/word_wrap) method was made specifically to address this.

However, it inserts newlines instead of what you'd need for breaking lines in HTML (such as encasing different lines in their own `<p>` tags).  I'd implement that functionality as a helper method after taking a good look at how the TextHelper's `word_wrap` method is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can break string as follows:

```
head_line = @user.headline.scan(/.{1,50}/)
```

In your case you can use `word_wrap`:

```
word_wrap(@user.headline, :line_width => 50)
```

Comment: omg, among both other answers this answer even doesn't solve the problem. It will not break the headline after 50 characters as you said. Only after 100. When someone sees the answer they could misuse word_warp

Comment: Although the OP mentions characters, based on the example he has given the required output doesn't want the last word of the first line itself to be broken. `irb(main):003:0> "This is the line".scan(/.{1,10}/)
=> ["This is th", "e line"]`

Comment: @Anand what you said is correct, but if you use word_wrap it will - and I quote: `This method breaks on the first whitespace character that does not exceed line_width` so the simplest use for this would be to use word_wrap. Just wanted to give you a comment. But thanks for noticing for `.scan()`. I gave you +1 ;)

Comment: @Aleks : My reference was to @codeit's first solution. The 2nd solution will work if `:line_width` is changed to 50 as mentioned in your answer. And guess who gave you a +1?  :-)

Comment: @Anand hehe, I could have guessed ;)) thank you a lot :)) combined effort always gives good solution ;)

Comment: @Aleks I haven't misused answer. I just wanted to give other solution.  The question title says breaking string. So my solution works. And I just suggested the second to use. I don't meant to get accept my answer get upvotes.

Comment: @codeit Yes, it works now, when you edited. To put 100 in order to brake line wouldn't do what was asked. It could point other users to use 100 to break line after 50 characters. And when they see it is not working, they could give up from this approach, that is why I had to say something. And who cares about the points. I have first registered to stackoverflow to put an answer to my very own question so others could benefit from it.

Comment: @Aleks question is bit confusing. first he asked to break 50 chars then in example he told 100. That's why I was confused and provided for 100

Comment: @codeit yes, you are right about that. he mentioned 100 three times and 50 only once. I have undo my -1 ;) the answer is now good, with comments added by Anand. Thanks anyway for giving multiple options for other to see. Bye :)